# Storing Polygon Datastructure in HDF5

Tags: hdf5

I'm new to HDF5 and I want to use it in order to store/read 2D polygons to/from disk. The polygons are represented by a data structure which can be visualized as follows:

```
polygon:
+- outer_polygon:
|  +- vertex1:
|  |  - coords(x,y)
|  |  - property1
|  |  - property2
|  |  - ...
|  +- vertex2:
|  |  ...
|  ...
+- inner_polygon1:
|  ...
...
```

So each polygon has an outer polygon and a variable number of inner polygons. Each outer/inner polygon has a variable number of vertices and each vertex has a fixed number of properties aside of its coordinates.

My question is: What would be the best way to structure this kind of data inside the HDF5 file? At the moment I see two possibilities:

1. Create compound data structures that represent the polygons and their building blocks (vertices, inner/outer polygons etc). This approach seems to be complicated.
2. Using groups in order to arrange the data, i.e., one group for each polygon and a subgroup for outer- and each inner polygon, etc. I assume this would be much easier than option 1, but I ask myself if access to the data and/or iterating over it would be inefficient?

Any help or advises on how to structure the polygons inside the HDF5 file in the best way would be much appreciated!

Comment: Questions: are the vertex coordinates unique to each polygon, or are they used for multiple polygons? e.g., is `vertex1` only used for the 1st polygon's outer loop? or used again? Same for properties: are `property1` and property2` reused for other polygons? What do you mean by compound data structure? a heterogeneous 2d array of data? If so, the ragged data structures to support the variable number vertices and inner loops is complicated. Finally, what language are you going to use?

Comment: Hi @kcw78. The vertices are "owned" by the polygons, i.e., the vertex object is unique to the polygon but there can be other polygons having vertices with equal coordinates. The same holds for the properties. Compound datatypes are introduced in the HDF5 standard see for example [here](https://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/HDF5-1.8.7/H5.intro.html#Intro-PMCreateCompound).

Comment: Got it. I work with python and h5py/pytables.  In Python, compound datatypes are represented with numpy record arrays.  Is a Python solution OK, or do you need a C++ or Fortran example? Note: Since this is schema design, you could convert a Python example to another language.